# Directory Index with Default Handler

Tags: apache

If I use the `SetHandler default-handler` option, I can no longer have an index for all the files in the directory. That is, `Options +Indexes` breaks. Is there a way to fix this or is there an alternate way to listing files in a directory using Apache?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
<Directory /srv/html/test>
        <Files ?*>
                SetHandler default-handler
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

It should set the default handler on all files with a filename of 1 character or longer. Autoindexing still works (if you have that configured, that is).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an index for all the files in the directory. Are you trying to do

/index.php

or run some other script and when you do

/

you want the index of the directory? To see a list of files in a directory use this

```
<Directory /this/is/the/list/directory>
  Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

Have a look here...

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: I just would like to show a list of all the files, but not allow the user to execute any server side scripts. In essence, I would like to create a folder serving only static files.